# Remove node from xmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xmldocument

I am trying to remove some nodes from XML document based on input but getting below error...

The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

```
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(filePath);
        if (document == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to load document.");

        foreach (string xPath in xPaths)
        {

            XmlNodeList oldChild = document.SelectNodes(xPath, mgr);
            if (oldChild != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in oldChild)
                {
                    document.RemoveChild(child);
                }
            }
        }

        document.Save(filePath);
```

Can anyone help me with what I am missign here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RemoveChild method working on direct child of the node. you are trying to remove some inner (not first generation) node by accessing the root node - the document.
The trick here is to get the parent node and remove the child from it.

```
child.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child)
```